# Does Deadpool ever go on the Haunted Segway Tour?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

At the start of *Deadpool* when Deadpool first gets into Dopinder's taxi he picks up a leaflet entitled "Haunted Segway Tours" and pockets it. You can see this at the start of [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLrYVcmL60s).

[image: Leaflets in the taxi]

Does Deadpool ever take the Haunted Segway Tour?

Comment: Is the tour haunted or are the segways haunted?

Comment: @Thunderforge The logo promises zombies riding segways, so both?

Comment: @Thunderforge that's a good follow-up question.

Comment: This was probably intended to be a joke, but haunted Segway tours are [real](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g35805-d1520104-r143451005-Absolutely_Chicago_Segway_Tours-Chicago_Illinois.html).

Comment: @Laurel aye I had seen they were real and most certainly a joke but these sorts of jokes in Deadpool sometimes go somewhere else, I.e. if he actually did it.

Comment: I've twitted at the writers to see if they had any plans for him to visit the tour